# PyQGIS: Properly trigger actionPan() tool when feature is added

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I wrote a plugin which creates a custom map tool that adds features. I would like to cleanly connect to the pan tool after a feature is added. I've done it in the following way and it works, but I get the QMessageBox an increasing amount of times as I use the plugin. Any suggestions on a cleaner/better way to do this?

```
def initGui(self):
    self.action.triggered.connect(self.run)
    self.moreAction.triggered.connect(self.runWithMoreStuff)
    self.clickTool.connect(self.addToMyLayer)

def setPanTool(self):
    self.iface.actionPan().trigger()
    QMessageBox.information(None, 'debug', 'pantriggered')

def addToMyLayer(self):
    self.myLayer.addFeature().trigger()

def addToAnotherLayer(self):
    self.anotherLayer.addFeature().trigger()

def run(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.clickTool)
    self.myLayer.featureAdded.connect(self.setPanTool)

def runWithMoreStuff(self):
    self.canvas.setMapTool(self.clickTool)
    self.myLayer.featureAdded.connect(self.addToMyLayer)
    self.anotherLayer.featureAdded.connect(self.setPanTool)
```

The idea is if one button is pushed, i'll add just the one feature then set the pan tool. If the other button is pushed, i'll add a feature, then another feature on another layer, then set the pan tool.

Comment: Can't you call actionPan().trigger() after you have done your feature add logic?

Comment: @NathanW I tried adding just a small snippet, but i've now realized I should have give you more code to explain why it's important that I do it in this way.